# How to get the service IP in Kubernetes?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cluster-computing, kubernetes

I ran a local cluster according to its official doc [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md). I followed the steps and it worked properly until I set a replica and tried to exposed it. I mean:

```
./kubectl expose rc nginx --port=80
```

the output is this:

```
NAME      LABELS      SELECTOR    IP(S)     PORT(S)
nginx     run=nginx   run=nginx             80/TCP
```

When I tried another time it sayed the the same service is running. How can I figure out the IP?

Answer (score 29):

```
kubectl get service/servicename -o jsonpath='{.spec.clusterIP}'
```

Comment: Much better to extract only the needed information instead of grepping afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

The IP should be the external IP of your master-node.
If you're running locally it should be localhost or your VM.

Of course with the given port added.

```
127.0.0.1:80
```

for example.

PS: Be sure you have containers/pods running already by running:

```
kubectl get pods
```

If this doesn't work, I would suggest proxying it, for test-purposes at least.

[Kubectl proxy](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/kubectl/proxy)

Comment: Thank you @NegatioN for your answer. I ran the `./kubectl get services` this and it gave me the ip.

Comment: how to find the `external IP of master-node`

Answer (score 3):

```
kubectl get svc <your-service> -o yaml | grep ip
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

`kubectl get svc <service-name> -o yaml | grep clusterIP`

or for example:

`kubectl describe svc <service-name> | grep IP`

Answer (score 0):

For convenient reference:

```
curl `kc describe svc nginx | grep IP | awk '{print $2}'`
```

And as a `kurl` bash function...

```
## for curling services by name...
kurl() {
  name=$1
  path=$2
  add=`kc describe svc $name | grep IP | awk '{print $2}'`$path
  # echo "hitting $add"
  curl $add
}
# kurl nginx :8080/some/path/you/want
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative command:

```
kubectl get -o template service/servicename --template='{{.spec.clusterIP}}'
```

Check `kubectl get --help`